# r: subsetting with square brackets not working

Tags: r, subset

I made data frame called x:

```
a  b
1  2
3  NA
3  32
21 7
12 8
```

When I run

```
y <- x["a">2,]
```

The object y returned is identical to x. If I run

```
y <- x["a" == 1,]
```

y is an empty frame.

I made sure that the names of the x data frame have no white spaces (I named them myself with names() ) and also that a and are numeric.

PS: If I try

```
 y <- x["a">2]
```

y is also returned as identical to x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making an error in referencing the column of your `data.frame` `x`.

`"a">2` means character `a` bigger than two, not variable `a` of `data.frame` `x`. You need to add either `x$a` or `x["a"]` to reference your `data.frame` column.

try

`y <- x[x$a >2 ,]`

or

`y <- x[x["a"] >2 ,]`

or even more clear

```
ix <- x["a"] > 2

y <- x[ix,]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative would be using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)

y <- x[ a > 2, ]

y <- x[ a == 1, ]
```